# flask-cors is not parsing the data from ajax client

Tags: json, ajax, python-3.x, flask, flask-cors

I am using flask for creating some endpoints for a blockchain project . I need to accept json data from ajax client . Since it is cros platform , i am using flask cors . But i cant seem to find a solution. It is not working

I have already tried doing

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origin = '*')
```

Basically my  client code is as follows .

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/ratings/new',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: json1,
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr)
        {
            $('body').append(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

And at my server i have an endpoint of

```
@app.route('/ratings/new', methods = ['POST','OPTIONS'])
def rating():
    values = request.get_json()
    if values == None:
        return "No data received", 400
    #ratings = values['rating']
    index = blockchain.new_ratings(values)

    response = {
        'Message': f'New transaction will be added to the block {index}',
        }
    response = jsonify(response)
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    return response, 201
```

At the server side i am not receiving the required data and at the client side i am getting the following error .

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/ratings/new' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Please help me solve this problem . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)` in your Flask code. And try. For more info, check this https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ beautiful doc.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake , make the withCredentials: false

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/ratings/new',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: json1,
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
        },
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr)
        {
            $('body').append(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be set on server side. Client(Browser) may make preflight request with header `Origin`.

Comment: I am doing CORS(app) . It should take care of it right . Thats what the latest documents said in flask-cors sites .